# Decrypting customer data on the client side

Tags: encryption, web-applications

I have a web app which my customers use to allow their employees to exchange documents. So, employee A1 can upload a document which employee A2 can later access given that both are employees of customer A. However, employees of any other customers are not allowed to access files uploaded by A1.

I would like to extend the web app to support secure documents. This means that I would have to encrypt document content before storing it on my server. In order to reduce liability I would like NOT to be able to decrypt the document content. So, ideally the content would be decrypted on the client (browser) side.

I have considered solutions that require an extra decryption/encryption service to be deployed on the customer side, but I don't like the extra management overhead that they require.

Assuming that my customers are large corporations and would have the typical infrastructure, e.g. LDAP, how would you propose to solve this problem without deploying extra services in customer environment?

Comment: Even if it were possible, where would your clients get the decryption keys from?

Comment: One solution would be to let the customer generate the key and store it in ldap. The web app will then use javascript ldap client to allow the employee trying to access the document to authenticate the web app to access ldap and retrieve the key. Of course, ldap would have to be secured, e.g. ldaps.

Comment: Well, then you're talking about encrypting/decrypting documents in JavaScript? I am not sure that it is possible or even practical.

Comment: There are other client-side technologies besides javascript, such as java applets, flash, silverlight, etc. I was wondering if anybody used them to encrypt/decrypt content. The question here is where to store the encryption key on the client. I mentioned LDAP, but maybe somebody has other ideas.

Comment: If you decide to go that route, I would suggest to stay away from document encryption (besides transport security like SSL of course) You do not want to get into key management game with your customers, as it is a headache of its own, (plus liability) Instead, you may approach this as many storage solutions tend to do these day - they do not encrypt, but rather obfuscate by separating the actual documents from their metadata and making the link between the metadata and the content very hard to reverse engineer.

Comment: Even if you hack into their systems and steal their document stores, you won't be able to get the full picture w/o executing their server-side code. That's how Google stores all of the customers' data (Gmail attachments, Drive, Documents, etc.) IBM does that, too.

Comment: Interesting approach. So, the idea is to create an obfuscation function which will take document metadata and content as its inputs and produces obfuscated content as its output, right? Is this Google's patent http://www.google.com/patents/US8811612 a good example of what you are talking about?

Comment: I am not sure about the patent. However, IBM in their content management systems does the following: each document's metadata set has a unique ID (think document ID). Within the IBM software there is a "hidden" lookup function that allows to map that ID to the document attachment location on disk. Without knowing how this function works, there is no way to link the metadata to the attachment. Also, by design, there is no way to do the opposite - given an attachment location, find out its metadata. At the end, the more documents the storage system has, the more "secure" this approach is.

Comment: So, is the content of the document obfuscated or just its location? Obfuscating just the location is not acceptable for me case. If document content is obfuscated, what kind algorithm would you suggest?

Comment: From what I've seen, the document contents are not encrypted or obfuscated by default when stored. (Remember that encrypted/encoded documents cannot be indexed easily.) But such a mechanism can be added as an additional layer. I don't think I can suggest anything, as I am not an expert in that area, but if you go that route, you probably need something that would not demand lots of CPU resources.